# get_post_meta on a WP_Query call

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a WP_Query call to grab the offices from my WordPress website.

```
$offices = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'office',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
]);
```

which is returning many results such as:

```
Array (  
    [0] => WP_Post Object  
        (  
            [ID] => 52856  
            [post_author] => 2
        )  
      )
```

So now I'm wanting to loop through a call a while condition to grab the metadata using `get_post_meta` but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is what I have so far:

```
foreach ($offices as $office) {
    while ($offices->have_posts()) {
        get_post_meta($office, 'id', $office->id);
    }
}
```

This seems to just cause the infinite loop to be stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd loop seems superfluous.

```
foreach ($offices as $office) {
   $postMetaArray[$office->ID] = get_post_meta($office->ID, '', false);
}
```

Should get you an array of all the meta data keyed with its  ID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is an infinite loop.

```
foreach ($offices as $office) {
    while ($offices->have_posts()) {
        get_post_meta($office, 'id', $office->id);
    }
}
```

The foreach loop has no end as nothing is done with $office. You only need the while loop. And the arguments are not in the right order for [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

```
while ($offices->have_posts()) {

    get_post_meta( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false );

}
```